# WPF RichTextBox lettering bullets incorrectly

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, rtf

My company's EULA was created by the legal team in Word and saved as an RTF document. It looks fine in Word. It looks fine in an MFC rich edit control. But in a WPF `RichTextBox`, the bullets get lettered incorrectly; instead of the expected `(a)`, `(b)`, `(c)`, etc., they come out as `a.`, `a.`, `a.`.

Screenshot from Word:

> [image]

Screenshot from `RichTextBox`:

> [image]

I'm not expert enough in the RTF language to determine whether the issue is with the RTF code Word generates, the way `RichTextBox` renders it, or the way I'm configuring the control. For what it's worth, here's the C# code that populates it:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(@"c:\path\test.rtf",
    FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    rtb.SelectAll();
    rtb.Selection.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
}
```

And while I hesitate to include this due to its length, the actual RTF used to produce the screenshots is at the bottom. I distilled it from the original EULA by tearing out as much as I could without breaking things, but it still wound up being fairly long thanks to all the cruft Word adds.

Can anyone guess what might be wrong or suggest things I can do to narrow down the problem?

test.rtf:

```
{\rtf1\adeflang1025\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\adeff0\deff0\stshfdbch0\stshfloch37\stshfhich37\stshfbi37\deflang1033\deflangfe1033\themelang1033\themelangfe0\themelangcs0\noqfpromote {\stylesheet{\ql \li0\ri0\sa160\sl259\slmult1
\widctlpar\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0 \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs22\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0 \f37\fs22\lang1033\langfe1033\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033 \snext0 \sqformat \spriority0 Normal;}{\*\cs10 \additive 
\ssemihidden \sunhideused \spriority1 Default Paragraph Font;}{\*\ts11\tsrowd\trftsWidthB3\trpaddl108\trpaddr108\trpaddfl3\trpaddft3\trpaddfb3\trpaddfr3\tblind0\tblindtype3\tsvertalt\tsbrdrt\tsbrdrl\tsbrdrb\tsbrdrr\tsbrdrdgl\tsbrdrdgr\tsbrdrh\tsbrdrv 
\ql \li0\ri0\widctlpar\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0 \rtlch\fcs1 \af37\afs20\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0 \f37\fs20\lang1033\langfe1033\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033 \snext11 \ssemihidden \sunhideused Normal Table;}{
\s15\ql \li0\ri0\sa160\sl259\slmult1\widctlpar\tqc\tx4680\tqr\tx9360\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0 \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs22\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0 \f37\fs22\lang1033\langfe1033\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033 
\sbasedon0 \snext15 \slink16 \sunhideused \styrsid12016732 header;}{\*\cs16 \additive \rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \sbasedon10 \slink15 \slocked \styrsid12016732 Header Char;}{\s17\ql \li0\ri0\sa160\sl259\slmult1\widctlpar
\tqc\tx4680\tqr\tx9360\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0 \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs22\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0 \f37\fs22\lang1033\langfe1033\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033 \sbasedon0 \snext17 \slink18 \sunhideused \styrsid12016732 
footer;}{\*\cs18 \additive \rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \sbasedon10 \slink17 \slocked \styrsid12016732 Footer Char;}{\s19\ql \li0\ri0\nowidctlpar\wrapdefault\faauto\rin0\lin0\itap0 \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs20\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0 
\fs18\lang1024\langfe1024\cgrid\noproof\langnp1033\langfenp1033 \sbasedon17 \snext17 \slink20 \spriority0 \styrsid12016732 DocID;}{\*\cs20 \additive \f0\fs20\lang1024\langfe1024\noproof\langnp1033\langfenp1033 
\slink19 \slocked \spriority0 \styrsid12016732 DocID Char;}{\*\cs21 \additive \rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \fs16 \sbasedon10 \slocked \ssemihidden \sunhideused \styrsid11475954 annotation reference;}{\s22\ql \li0\ri0\sa160\sl259\slmult1
\widctlpar\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0 \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs20\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0 \f37\fs20\lang1033\langfe1033\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033 
\sbasedon0 \snext22 \slink23 \slocked \ssemihidden \sunhideused \styrsid11475954 annotation text;}{\*\cs23 \additive \rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \fs20 \sbasedon10 \slink22 \slocked \ssemihidden \styrsid11475954 Comment Text Char;}{
\s24\ql \li0\ri0\sa160\sl259\slmult1\widctlpar\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0 \rtlch\fcs1 \ab\af0\afs20\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0 \b\f37\fs20\lang1033\langfe1033\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033 
\sbasedon22 \snext22 \slink25 \slocked \ssemihidden \sunhideused \styrsid11475954 annotation subject;}{\*\cs25 \additive \rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \b\fs20 \sbasedon23 \slink24 \slocked \ssemihidden \styrsid11475954 Comment Subject Char;}{
\s26\ql \li0\ri0\widctlpar\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0 \rtlch\fcs1 \af39\afs18\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0 \f39\fs18\lang1033\langfe1033\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033 
\sbasedon0 \snext26 \slink27 \slocked \ssemihidden \sunhideused \styrsid11475954 Balloon Text;}{\*\cs27 \additive \rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \f39\fs18 \sbasedon10 \slink26 \slocked \ssemihidden \styrsid11475954 Balloon Text Char;}}{\*\listtable
{\list\listtemplateid2011486062\listhybrid{\listlevel\levelnfc23\levelnfcn23\leveljc0\leveljcn0\levelfollow0\levelstartat1\levelspace0\levelindent0{\leveltext\leveltemplateid0\'01\u-3913 ?;}{\levelnumbers;}\f3 \fi-360\li720\lin720 }{\listlevel\levelnfc23
\levelnfcn23\leveljc0\leveljcn0\levelfollow0\levelstartat1\levelspace0\levelindent0{\leveltext\leveltemplateid1\'01o;}{\levelnumbers;}\f2 \fi-360\li1440\lin1440 }{\listlevel\levelnfc23\levelnfcn23\leveljc0\leveljcn0\levelfollow0\levelstartat1\levelspace0
\levelindent0{\leveltext\leveltemplateid2\'01\u-3929 ?;}{\levelnumbers;}\f10 \fi-360\li2160\lin2160 }{\listlevel\levelnfc23\levelnfcn23\leveljc0\leveljcn0\levelfollow0\levelstartat1\levelspace0\levelindent0{\leveltext\leveltemplateid3
\'01\u-3913 ?;}{\levelnumbers;}\f3 \fi-360\li2880\lin2880 }{\listlevel\levelnfc23\levelnfcn23\leveljc0\leveljcn0\levelfollow0\levelstartat1\levelspace0\levelindent0{\leveltext\leveltemplateid4\'01o;}{\levelnumbers;}\f2 \fi-360\li3600\lin3600 }{\listlevel
\levelnfc23\levelnfcn23\leveljc0\leveljcn0\levelfollow0\levelstartat1\levelspace0\levelindent0{\leveltext\leveltemplateid5\'01\u-3929 ?;}{\levelnumbers;}\f10 \fi-360\li4320\lin4320 }{\listlevel\levelnfc23\levelnfcn23\leveljc0\leveljcn0\levelfollow0
\levelstartat1\levelspace0\levelindent0{\leveltext\leveltemplateid6\'01\u-3913 ?;}{\levelnumbers;}\f3 \fi-360\li5040\lin5040 }{\listlevel\levelnfc23\levelnfcn23\leveljc0\leveljcn0\levelfollow0\levelstartat1\levelspace0\levelindent0{\leveltext
\leveltemplateid7\'01o;}{\levelnumbers;}\f2 \fi-360\li5760\lin5760 }{\listlevel\levelnfc23\levelnfcn23\leveljc0\leveljcn0\levelfollow0\levelstartat1\levelspace0\levelindent0{\leveltext\leveltemplateid8\'01\u-3929 ?;}{\levelnumbers;}\f10 
\fi-360\li6480\lin6480 }{\listname ;}\listid935794633}{\list\listtemplateid-2000099728\listhybrid{\listlevel\levelnfc4\levelnfcn4\leveljc0\leveljcn0\levelfollow0\levelstartat1\levelspace0\levelindent0{\leveltext\leveltemplateid0\'03(\'00);}{\levelnumbers
\'02;}\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \fi-360\li720\lin720 }{\listlevel\levelnfc4\levelnfcn4\leveljc0\leveljcn0\levelfollow0\levelstartat1\levelspace0\levelindent0{\leveltext\leveltemplateid1\'02\'01.;}{\levelnumbers\'01;}\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 
\fi-360\li1440\lin1440 }{\listlevel\levelnfc2\levelnfcn2\leveljc2\leveljcn2\levelfollow0\levelstartat1\levelspace0\levelindent0{\leveltext\leveltemplateid2\'02\'02.;}{\levelnumbers\'01;}\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \fi-180\li2160\lin2160 }{\listlevel
\levelnfc0\levelnfcn0\leveljc0\leveljcn0\levelfollow0\levelstartat1\levelspace0\levelindent0{\leveltext\leveltemplateid3\'02\'03.;}{\levelnumbers\'01;}\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \fi-360\li2880\lin2880 }{\listlevel\levelnfc4\levelnfcn4\leveljc0\leveljcn0
\levelfollow0\levelstartat1\levelspace0\levelindent0{\leveltext\leveltemplateid4\'02\'04.;}{\levelnumbers\'01;}\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \fi-360\li3600\lin3600 }{\listlevel\levelnfc2\levelnfcn2\leveljc2\leveljcn2\levelfollow0\levelstartat1\levelspace0
\levelindent0{\leveltext\leveltemplateid5\'02\'05.;}{\levelnumbers\'01;}\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \fi-180\li4320\lin4320 }{\listlevel\levelnfc0\levelnfcn0\leveljc0\leveljcn0\levelfollow0\levelstartat1\levelspace0\levelindent0{\leveltext
\leveltemplateid6\'02\'06.;}{\levelnumbers\'01;}\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \fi-360\li5040\lin5040 }{\listlevel\levelnfc4\levelnfcn4\leveljc0\leveljcn0\levelfollow0\levelstartat1\levelspace0\levelindent0{\leveltext\leveltemplateid7
\'02\'07.;}{\levelnumbers\'01;}\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \fi-360\li5760\lin5760 }{\listlevel\levelnfc2\levelnfcn2\leveljc2\leveljcn2\levelfollow0\levelstartat1\levelspace0\levelindent0{\leveltext\leveltemplateid8\'02\'08.;}{\levelnumbers\'01;}
\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \fi-180\li6480\lin6480 }{\listname ;}\listid1118135182}}{\*\listoverridetable{\listoverride\listid935794633\listoverridecount0\ls1}{\listoverride\listid1118135182\listoverridecount9{\lfolevel\listoverridestartat\levelstartat1}
{\lfolevel\listoverridestartat\levelstartat1}{\lfolevel\listoverridestartat\levelstartat1}{\lfolevel\listoverridestartat\levelstartat1}{\lfolevel\listoverridestartat\levelstartat1}{\lfolevel\listoverridestartat\levelstartat1}{\lfolevel\listoverridestartat
\levelstartat1}{\lfolevel\listoverridestartat\levelstartat1}{\lfolevel\listoverridestartat\levelstartat1}\ls2}}{\*\rsidtbl \rsid5445\rsid213040\rsid458779\rsid594337\rsid679387\rsid738860\rsid1407444\rsid1649845\rsid1849016\rsid2059637\rsid2849649
\rsid2959143\rsid3163417\rsid3358015\rsid3549178\rsid3741932\rsid4533847\rsid5199835\rsid5863312\rsid5991279\rsid6173664\rsid6318447\rsid7493734\rsid7879023\rsid7893963\rsid8345806\rsid8944987\rsid9124447\rsid9375898\rsid9599121\rsid9971206\rsid10440622
\rsid10512568\rsid10829736\rsid11471938\rsid11475954\rsid11616672\rsid11798167\rsid11820934\rsid12016732\rsid12151919\rsid12197023\rsid13658072\rsid13706787\rsid13913264\rsid14096362\rsid14439285\rsid14556623\rsid15163148\rsid15209186\rsid16584960}
{\mmathPr\mmathFont34\mbrkBin0\mbrkBinSub0\msmallFrac0\mdispDef1\mlMargin0\mrMargin0\mdefJc1\mwrapRight1\mintLim0\mnaryLim1}{\info{\creatim\yr2018\mo10\dy1\hr10\min1}{\revtim\yr2018\mo10\dy1\hr10\min2}
{\version3}{\edmins0}{\nofpages1}{\nofwords18}{\nofchars107}{\nofcharsws124}{\vern49167}}{\*\xmlnstbl

 {\xmlns1 http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml}}
\paperw12240\paperh15840\margl1440\margr1440\margt1440\margb1440\gutter0\ltrsect 
\widowctrl\ftnbj\aenddoc\trackmoves0\trackformatting1\donotembedsysfont0\relyonvml0\donotembedlingdata0\grfdocevents0\validatexml0\showplaceholdtext0\ignoremixedcontent0\saveinvalidxml0\showxmlerrors0\horzdoc\dgmargin\dghspace120\dgvspace120\dghorigin1440
\dgvorigin1440\dghshow0\dgvshow3\jcompress\viewkind1\viewscale138\rsidroot8345806 \fet0{\*\wgrffmtfilter 2450}\ilfomacatclnup0{\*\ftnsep \ltrpar \pard\plain \ltrpar
\ql \li0\ri0\widctlpar\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0\pararsid12016732 \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs22\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0 \f37\fs22\lang1033\langfe1033\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033 {\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid1649845 
\chftnsep 
\par }}{\*\ftnsepc \ltrpar \pard\plain \ltrpar\ql \li0\ri0\widctlpar\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0\pararsid12016732 \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs22\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0 \f37\fs22\lang1033\langfe1033\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033 {
\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid1649845 \chftnsepc 
\par }}{\*\aftnsep \ltrpar \pard\plain \ltrpar\ql \li0\ri0\widctlpar\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0\pararsid12016732 \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs22\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0 \f37\fs22\lang1033\langfe1033\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033 {
\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid1649845 \chftnsep 
\par }}{\*\aftnsepc \ltrpar \pard\plain \ltrpar\ql \li0\ri0\widctlpar\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0\pararsid12016732 \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs22\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0 \f37\fs22\lang1033\langfe1033\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033 {
\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid1649845 \chftnsepc 
\par }}\ltrpar \sectd \ltrsect\linex0\sectdefaultcl\sftnbj {\headerr \ltrpar \pard\plain \ltrpar\s15\ql \li0\ri0\sa160\sl259\slmult1\widctlpar\tqc\tx4680\tqr\tx9360\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0 \rtlch\fcs1 
\af0\afs22\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0 \f37\fs22\lang1033\langfe1033\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033 {\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid12016732 
\par }}{\footerl \ltrpar \pard\plain \ltrpar\s19\ql \li0\ri0\nowidctlpar\wrapdefault\faauto\rin0\lin0\itap0\pararsid8944987 \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs20\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0 \fs18\lang1024\langfe1024\cgrid\noproof\langnp1033\langfenp1033 {\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 
\ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid2959143 {\*\bkmkstart _iDocIDFielda48ad11f-7dba-4e18-a779-7b81}{\*\bkmkend _iDocIDFielda48ad11f-7dba-4e18-a779-7b81}24433405.3
\par }\pard \ltrpar\s19\ql \li0\ri0\nowidctlpar\wrapdefault\faauto\rin0\lin0\itap0 {\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid2959143 {\*\bkmkstart _iDocIDField1a4ca757-909e-4c25-9870-1588}{\*\bkmkend _iDocIDField1a4ca757-909e-4c25-9870-1588}27573085.2
\par }}{\footerr \ltrpar \pard\plain \ltrpar\s19\ql \li0\ri0\nowidctlpar\wrapdefault\faauto\rin0\lin0\itap0\pararsid13913264 \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs20\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0 \fs18\lang1024\langfe1024\cgrid\noproof\langnp1033\langfenp1033 {\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 
\ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid2959143 {\*\bkmkstart _iDocIDField0f33ea61-4cfb-4b48-891c-d9c0}{\*\bkmkend _iDocIDField0f33ea61-4cfb-4b48-891c-d9c0}24433405.3
\par }\pard \ltrpar\s19\ql \li0\ri0\nowidctlpar\wrapdefault\faauto\rin0\lin0\itap0 {\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid2959143 
\par }}{\footerf \ltrpar \pard\plain \ltrpar\s19\ql \li0\ri0\nowidctlpar\wrapdefault\faauto\rin0\lin0\itap0\pararsid6173664 \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs20\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0 \fs18\lang1024\langfe1024\cgrid\noproof\langnp1033\langfenp1033 {\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 
\ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid2959143 {\*\bkmkstart _iDocIDField04c8f8bc-5a61-493b-8926-6071}{\*\bkmkend _iDocIDField04c8f8bc-5a61-493b-8926-6071}24433405.3
\par }\pard \ltrpar\s19\ql \li0\ri0\nowidctlpar\wrapdefault\faauto\rin0\lin0\itap0 {\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid2959143 {\*\bkmkstart _iDocIDField3d2d75c6-0111-4767-8713-53fc}{\*\bkmkend _iDocIDField3d2d75c6-0111-4767-8713-53fc}27573085.2
\par }}{\*\pnseclvl1\pnucrm\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxta .}}{\*\pnseclvl2\pnucltr\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxta .}}{\*\pnseclvl3\pndec\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxta .}}{\*\pnseclvl4\pnlcltr\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxta )}}
{\*\pnseclvl5\pndec\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxtb (}{\pntxta )}}{\*\pnseclvl6\pnlcltr\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxtb (}{\pntxta )}}{\*\pnseclvl7\pnlcrm\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxtb (}{\pntxta )}}{\*\pnseclvl8
\pnlcltr\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxtb (}{\pntxta )}}{\*\pnseclvl9\pnlcrm\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxtb (}{\pntxta )}}\pard\plain \ltrpar\qj \li0\ri0\nowidctlpar\wrapdefault\faauto\rin0\lin0\itap0\pararsid5991279 \rtlch\fcs1 
\af0\afs22\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0 \f37\fs22\lang1033\langfe1033\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033 {\rtlch\fcs1 \af40 \ltrch\fcs0 \f40\insrsid13706787 Licensee agrees that }{\rtlch\fcs1 \af40 \ltrch\fcs0 \f40\insrsid9971206 blah blah blah}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af40 
\ltrch\fcs0 \f40\insrsid5991279\charrsid5991279 
\par {\listtext\pard\plain\ltrpar \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs22 \ltrch\fcs0 \f40\fs22\insrsid13706787 \hich\af40\dbch\af0\loch\f40 (a)\tab}}\pard \ltrpar\qj \fi-360\li720\ri0\nowidctlpar\wrapdefault\faauto\ls2\rin0\lin720\itap0\pararsid5991279 {\rtlch\fcs1 \af40 
\ltrch\fcs0 \f40\insrsid13706787 W}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af40 \ltrch\fcs0 \f40\insrsid5991279\charrsid5991279 hile }{\rtlch\fcs1 \af40 \ltrch\fcs0 \f40\insrsid9971206 blah blah blah}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af40 \ltrch\fcs0 \f40\insrsid5991279\charrsid5991279 
\par {\listtext\pard\plain\ltrpar \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs22 \ltrch\fcs0 \f40\fs22\insrsid5991279\charrsid5991279 \hich\af40\dbch\af0\loch\f40 (b)\tab}To the extent that }{\rtlch\fcs1 \af40 \ltrch\fcs0 \f40\insrsid9971206 blah blah blah}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af40 
\ltrch\fcs0 \f40\insrsid5991279\charrsid5991279 
\par {\listtext\pard\plain\ltrpar \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs22 \ltrch\fcs0 \f40\fs22\insrsid5991279\charrsid9971206 \hich\af40\dbch\af0\loch\f40 (c)\tab}}\pard \ltrpar\qj \fi-360\li720\ri0\nowidctlpar\wrapdefault\faauto\ls2\rin0\lin720\itap0\pararsid9971206 {
\rtlch\fcs1 \af40 \ltrch\fcs0 \f40\insrsid5991279\charrsid9971206 To the extent that }{\rtlch\fcs1 \af40 \ltrch\fcs0 \f40\insrsid9971206 blah blah blah}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af40 \ltrch\fcs0 \f40\insrsid5991279 
\par }}
```

Comment: Not a solution, but it might help you to narrow down the cause if you use wordpad or some similar basic RTF editor to produce your document rather than word. The wordpad document for your sample text is a fraction of what word produced for you, with just the minimal of formatting tags. I did notice that wordpad doesn't have an option for an ordered list with the item labels in brackets, so maybe that format isn't actually supported by the RTF specification.

Comment: As an experiment, I copied the full text of the real EULA out of Word, pasted into WordPad, saved, and loaded the result into a RichTextBox. This was a step forward in that the offending bullets are now labeled `a.`, `b.`, and `c.` instead of `a.`, `a.` and `a.`, but they're supposed to be `(a)`, `(b)`, and `(c)` (and that's what both Word and WordPad show for the same file). Very odd.